# JSON Array in Newtonsoft using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, json.net

I am pretty new to using JSON and Newtonsoft together and I am trying to replicate this format without success using JArray(). Does anyone have any ideas on how this can be accomplished?

```
   "attrList":[
      {
         "name":"Attendee Status",
         "val":"Accepted"
      },
      {
         "name":"Attendee Type",
         "val":"Attendee"
      }
   ]
```

Comment: The error I keep running into is the keys being the same.

Comment: What you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using manual `JArray` creation, you can do it as follows:

```
var root = new JObject
(
    new JProperty("attrList",
        new JArray
        (
            new JObject
            (
                new JProperty("name", "Attendee Status"),
                new JProperty("val", "Accepted")
            ),                  
            new JObject
            (
                new JProperty("name", "Attendee Type"),
                new JProperty("val", "Attendee")
            )
        )
    )
);
```

You wrote *The error I keep running into is the keys being the same*, so you are probably doing something like this instead:

```
var root = new JObject
(
    new JProperty("attrList",
        new JArray
        (
            new JObject
            (
                new JProperty("name", "Attendee Status"),
                new JProperty("val", "Accepted"),
                new JProperty("name", "Attendee Type"),
                new JProperty("val", "Attendee")
            )
        )
    )
);
```

Notice that only one inner object is being created rather than two?  If you forget to allocate both objects you will end up trying to add the properties `"name"` and `"val"` twice, thereby reproducing the problem.

Sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/8arefV).

See also [Creating JSON: Manually Creating JSON](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CreatingLINQtoJSON.htm).

Comment: Thank you! I was not aware I could use JObject like that.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Parent
{
    public List<Attribute> attrList{ get; set; }
}

public class Attribute
{
    public string name{ get; set; }
    public string val{ get; set; }
}

var parsedParent = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Parent>(
   "{ 'attrList':[ { 'name':'Attendee Status', 'val':'Accepted' }, { 'name':'Attendee Type', 'val':'Attendee' } ] }"
);
```